Why we can find $(-\frac{3}{2})!$ but not $(-1)!$?
I understand that the gamma function is an extension of the factorial function to complex numbers and that it is not defined for non positive integer values. For example, we cannot find the value of $\Gamma(0)$, which corresponds to $(-1)!$, but we can find the value of $\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2})$, which corresponds to $(-\frac{3}{2})!$, and it evaluates to $-2\sqrt{\pi}$. How can this be possible?
I plotted both graphs on Desmos, and it is clear that the function $ x^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-x}$ is always greater than the function $ x^{-1}e^{-x} $ in the domain $(0, 1)$. The latter function is divergent, and the area under the curve from $0$ to $1$ tends to infinity. Therefore, the area under the former curve in the interval $(0, 1)$ is clearly greater than the area under the latter curve in $(0, 1)$. Logically, $(-\frac{3}{2})!$ should also tend to infinity. However, we know its value, which is $-2\sqrt{\pi}$. How is this possible?
Additionally, in the graph, we see the area is positive, but $\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2})$ is a negative number. How can this be?


That integral is not what is used to define $\Gamma$ for negative values.

Please enlighten which intergral is used for negative numbers?

A formula as a Weierstrass product is one that works everywhere.

FYI, this site natively supports most LaTeX maths expressions. All you need to do is enclose them in $ for inline or $$ for display maths. For example, $x^{-1}e^{-x}$ produces $x^{-1}e^{-x}$, whereas $$x^{-1}e^{-x}$$ produces$$x^{-1}e^{-x}$$

The integral representation,
$$\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t,$$
is valid only when $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.
Once $\Gamma(s)$ has been defined for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$ via the above representation, then it its domain is extend to all of $s \in \mathbb{C}$ so that the functional equation
$$ \Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s) $$
remains valid. So, for example,
$$ \Gamma(s)
= \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{s}
= \frac{1}{s} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{s}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t $$
for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > -1$,
$$ \Gamma(s)
= \frac{\Gamma(s+2)}{s(s+1)}
= \frac{1}{s(s+1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{s+1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t $$
for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > -2$, etc.
If you want an expansion that is valid for all $s$, assume first that $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$. Then starting from the above integral representation, we can expand $\Gamma(s)$ as
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(s)
&= \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t + \int_{0}^{1} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{1} t^{s+n-1} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n + s)}.
\end{align*}
Now we can check that RHS converges locally uniformly for $s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, -1, -2, \ldots\}$. So, both sides define meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ that coincide on $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$. Therefore we conclude from the principle of analytic continuation that both sides are equal on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

this is honestly a very nice explicit demonstration/example of analytic continuation nice
